# PHP to create MySQL database?

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I am learning PHP & MySQL at this moment. I created a simple HTML form & PHP script to generate MySQL database, but when I tested it, not working. After submitting the form, I got "*Server error. The website encountered an error while retrieving http://www.xxxxx.com/php/createDB.php. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly.*"

My HTML form is as follow:

```
<body>
<h2>Please enter the following information to create a new database.</h2>
<form action="createDB.php" method="post">
Server Name: <input type="text" name="servername">
Database Name: <input type="text" name="databasename">
User Name: <input type="text" name="username">
Password: <input type="text" name="password">
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
</body>
```

My PHP script is as follow:

```
<?php
$server = $_POST['servername'];
$dbname = $_POST['databasename'];
$user = $_POST['username'];
$pwd = $_POST['password'];

$con = mysql_connect($server,$user,$pwd);
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
if (mysql_query("CREATE DATABASE" $dbname,$con))
{
echo "Database " .$dbname ." created!";
}
else
{
echo "Error creating database: " . mysql_error();
}
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Is there anything wrong with this?

Thanks.

hc.

Comment: You have a syntax error in your PHP code: `mysql_query("CREATE DATABASE" $dbname,$con))`. That being said, this is a terrible idea.

Comment: MySQL extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

Comment: First, read about bobby tables :) http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: @PeterSzymkowski Presumably whoever is running this will need DB credentials, so SQL injection is a bit of a moot point since they own the freaking database.

Comment: @NullUserException uh i guess you are right:))) my bad

Comment: @NullUserException Is this correct? mysql_query("CREATE DATABASE $dbname",$con))

Answer (score 3):

There is an error into your PHP script, so PHP could not parse it.

The error :

```
if (mysql_query("CREATE DATABASE" $dbname,$con))
```

Try this to repair it (don't forget the space between DATABASE and "):

```
if (mysql_query("CREATE DATABASE " . $dbname,$con))
```

Comment: The script works but I got this "Could not connect: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)". How do you link the $pwd to MySQL server password?

Comment: Oopps..it works. Ignore my previous comment. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Many PHP programmers are still not using Try Catch, its always a good idea to implement graceful exception handling in your code, the benefits are two fold: easier to debug your code based on the stack trace sent back and also on the frontend you can provide meaningful messages to your users and/or take action programmatically at a higher level.

Having said this, I cannot remember when last I've seen hand-rolled MySql connection code, guess its the era of frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this , its work for me and i also tested in my localhost.

```
<form action="createDB.php" method="post">
    Server Name: <input type="text" name="servername">
    Database Name: <input type="text" name="databasename">
    User Name: <input type="text" name="username">
    Password: <input type="text" name="password">
    <input type="submit" value="submit" name="send">
</form>
```

**PHP Script**

```
<?php
  if(isset($_REQUEST['send']))
  {
    $server = $_POST['servername'];
    $dbname = $_POST['databasename'];
    $user = $_POST['username'];
    $pwd = $_POST['password'];

    $con = mysql_connect($server,$user,$pwd);
    if (!$con)
    {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    if (mysql_query("CREATE DATABASE " . $dbname,$con))
    {
    echo "Database " .$dbname ." created!";
    }
    else
    {
    echo "Error creating database: " . mysql_error();
    }
    mysql_close($con);
  }
?>
```

Comment: @hanjaya , I have tested code in my localhost , define both script HTML and PHP script on same page. and when you submit form pass action on same page.

Comment: Hi, Is there any benefits to have both script and form defined on the same page?

Comment: I have defined both script and form on same page because of testing, you can also defined both separately.